# Using makefile to compile C,C++ code in python package

Tags: python, c, linux, makefile

I am trying to build a python package which uses [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to call some C libraries at runtime. 
These libraries are built using ARM based arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc and arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ compilers and require a makefile. Is there any neat way of calling this Makefile from the setup.py while my package is installed?

Comment: Use `subprocess` to call `make`?

Comment: Yeah that's an obvious solution. I was just wondering if there is an elegant way. Thanks!